# Javascript page transitions

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to create a fadein/fadeout effect for my pages in my Ruby on Rails app. I found a website, https://coderwall.com/p/t5ghhw/animated-page-transitions-in-rails-4-apps, that seemed to offer a reasonable guide, but it isn't working.

In each of my html files (except for application.html.erb), I have a div that encloses all of the content with a class called "primary-content." Then I have a css file, animate.css(adapted from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), with the following code:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
          animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
          animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

.fadeOutUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
          animation-name: fadeOutUp;
}
```

This css file is in my assets/css folder, and is called in the header of my application.html.erb file.

Then there's the javascript, in a file in the assets/javascripts folder. It's required in application.js and called in the header of application.html.erb--and, when it wasn't working, I also called it at the bottom of each view. The code reads:

```
document.addEventListener('page:change', function() {
        document.getElementById('primary-content').className += 'animated fadeInUp';
});
document.addEventListener('page:fetch', function() {
        document.getElementById('primary-content').className += 'animated fadeOutUp';
});
```

I'm aiming for the existing page to fade out upward, and the new page to fade in upward. Does anyone see what I'm missing? I don't have any experience with keyframes, or with using -webkit in css, but that's all borrowed from the animate.css site.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your css being required in using the sprockets in `application.css`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean . . . I import bootstrap-sprockets at the beginning of application.css, but I thought that animate.css, which is in the css folder, would be compiled into application.css at runtime. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: I was able to get it working on a rails new app with no issue by just dropping the code into application.css and application.js you can see them here. [Rails Page Change Animation](https://gist.github.com/11d6c3b43622f8f2b837)

It's possible the javascript is not firing do you have any errors on your javascript console?